# How would I tell the last time Apache served a file?

Tags: apache2, php

I'm trying to figure out how to tell the last time a .php file was served by Apache.

I have written an application on an Ubuntu Lamp stack with Mysql & PHP. I have 1000s of files and I'm trying to "clean House". I'd like to know how to list all the files in the folder by the last time Apache actually served it.

It this even possible?

*UPDATE*

Sorry, I should have been a little more detailed.

I'm looking for all files that would include every file that was included with a php script like `<?php include "i_cant_see_this_file_in_the_logs.php"; ?>`

Hopefully that shines a little more light.

Thank you.

Comment: Should be in /var/log/apache2/access.log.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `auditctl` or some sort of unix file-system auditing tool, but probably not retroactively. You would probably want apache to be running under a different user account, and then use the filesystem audit tool to track file-reads. A different solution that I'd be more comfortable using would be to add some debugging code to each php file (obviously not manually) which simply logs the name of the file and the date to a single file somewhere. I'd also create a subversion or git patch file after making this change so you can apply it and revert it as needed. After doing a full suite of testing, you can check the log file to see which files are absent (this can also be automated; I'd write a script compare the output of ls (sorted by name) with the log file (sorted by name and unique'd).